# I need an alternative to innerHtml

Tags: innerhtml

This is my code. I'm trying to find an alternative to using innerHTML at the end.

```
function randomBanners()

{

var allBanners=new Array();

allBanners[0]="< src='' />";

allBanners[1]="< src='' />";

allBanners[2]="< src='' />";

allBanners[3]="< src='' />";

var l =allBanners.length;

var r=Math.random();

var t=l * r;

var i = Math.floor(t);

document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = allBanners[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('header').text(allBanners[i]);
```

Or:

```
$('header').text(allBanners[i]);
```

In case that allBanners[] contain HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to create an image with a randomised `src` via DOM:

```
var banners= ['foo.gif', 'bar.jpeg', 'bof.png'];

var img= document.createElement('img');
img.src= banners[Math.floor(banners.length*Math.random())];
document.getElementById('header').appendChild(img);
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. THANK YOU SO MUCH. You have saved me from the apocalypse